How can I split state shapefiles in R?
I have the shapefiles of US states that I downloaded from the United States Census Bureau. Here is a link for the 2024 data as an example.
I'm working on a map in tableau and need to split a few of the states into two separate objects (ex. "North Florida" and "South Florida") so that they can be filled differently on the map. How would I go about this?
Ideally the split would be at the halfway point for the states I split.

Which one? Layer- or state-based?

State-based I think? I basically want to end up with two separate objects for certain states. So, for example, for NC instead of just having one object for nc I would have two- one for north NC and one for south NC

@Friede How-to questions don't require code, and OP included the data, which is externally available. Stack Overflow posts don't support attachments.

@TylerH, please clarify where to click on the linked page to download the data then. It is unclear to me.

If you update your question to include the actual download link for the data you are using (as opposed to just the landing page link), it will increase the chances of your question being reopened. Thanks, and happy coding!

@Friede Having to click an extra link or two, or hunt on a page for which link to click, is not the same as "you didn't provide data". If you aren't sure where on the page to download the data from the link provided by OP, ask about that. Don't make up problems the question doesn't actually have, instead.

The simplest way will be to find the centroid of the state and create a polygon for upper/lower half of the state. Below example of lower part for Florida:
florida <- geodata::gadm("USA", level = 1, path = "data") |>
  sf::st_as_sf() |>
  subset(NAME_1 == "Florida")

c <- sf::st_centroid(florida)

plot(sf::st_geometry(florida))
plot(sf::st_geometry(c), col = "red", add = TRUE)


Now let's take bounding box of state to get xmin, xmax and ymin, ymax coordinates, and create the polygon of the lower "half"

bb <- sf::st_bbox(florida)

lon <- c(bb["xmin"], bb["xmax"])
lat <- c(bb["ymin"], sf::st_coordinates(c)[1, "Y"])

lower_bb <- 
  data.frame(lon, lat) |>
    sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), 
             crs = "EPSG:4326") |>
    sf::st_bbox() |>
    sf::st_as_sfc() |>
    sf::st_as_sf()

plot(sf::st_geometry(florida))
plot(sf::st_geometry(lower_bb), add = TRUE, lty = 3)


And finally use the lower_bb polygon to find an intersection of it with our state:
florida_low <- sf::st_intersection(florida, lower_bb)

plot(sf::st_geometry(florida))
plot(sf::st_geometry(florida_low), col = "blue", add = TRUE)


The same shall be done for upper part of the state.

lon <- c(bb["xmin"], bb["xmax"])
lat <- c(sf::st_coordinates(c)[1, "Y"], bb["ymax"])

upper_bb <- 
  data.frame(lon, lat) |>
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), 
               crs = "EPSG:4326") |>
  sf::st_bbox() |>
  sf::st_as_sfc() |>
  sf::st_as_sf()

plot(sf::st_geometry(florida))
plot(sf::st_geometry(upper_bb), add = TRUE, lty = 3)



florida_up <- sf::st_intersection(florida, upper_bb)

plot(sf::st_geometry(florida))
plot(sf::st_geometry(florida_up), col = "green", add = TRUE)


Created on 2024-09-27 with reprex v2.1.0

I ran this and while it works for some states, it doesn't create multipolygons for all of them. For example, the upper half of florida results in a multiline string and the rest of the states a polygon. When I try to read out the data as a shapefile, I get the following error: Error: Feature creation failed.

Maybe check the geometry of your input features with sf::st_is_valid(). Or share a example of your code/data to point out the issues. BTW, there is {tigris} package for load census shapefiles/data, no need to download it by browser. Edited answer shows north of Florida as well, without any multilines.

You can create a latitudinal 'blade' across the centroid of the state polygon and use lwgeom::st_split() to divide the polygon. I have included an additional workflow if you then need to add the split state back to the original states data.
I recommend using the tigris() package to access US census data as it is way more convenient and includes some handy functions such as shift_geometry(), which shifts the non-contiguous states closer the the mainland for plotting purposes.
Note that because the CRS for the US census data is a geographic coordinate system (NAD83), this code will throw warnings. For your use case, you can safely ignore these.
library(tigris)
library(sf)
library(lwgeom)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Get census file (state boundaries)
states_sf <- states(year = 2024)

# or from previously downloaded zip file stored in your working directory
# downloaded from # https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2024/STATE/tl_2024_us_state.zip
# Modify file names to match your actual data
# states_sf <- st_read(unzip("tl_2024_us_state.zip", "tl_2024_us_state.shp"))

# Define name of state to split
state <- "Florida"

# Get state to split
state_sf <- filter(states_sf , NAME == state)

# Create latitudinal 'blade' at centroid of state
blade <- matrix(c(st_bbox(state_sf)[c(1, 3)],
                  rep(st_coordinates(st_centroid(state_sf))[2], 2)), , 2) |>
  st_linestring()

# Split state using blade, define North and South polygons
state_spt <- st_split(state_sf, blade) |>
  st_collection_extract() |>
  mutate(
    ns = if_else(
      st_coordinates(st_centroid(geometry))[, 2] > min(st_coordinates(blade)[,2]),
      "North", "South"
      )) |>
  group_by(across(-geometry)) |>
  summarise(geometry = st_union(geometry), .groups = "drop")

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = state_spt, aes(fill = ns)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())


If you need to combine the split state with the rest of the states.
# Do this only once (if combining more than one split state)
states_spt <- mutate(states_sf, ns = NA) |>
  filter(DIVISION != "0")

# Replace unsplit with split state 
states_spt1 <- states_spt |>
  filter(NAME != state) |>
  bind_rows(state_spt) 
  
# If you want non-contiguous states plotted close to mainland
states_splt2 <- shift_geometry(states_spt,
                       preserve_area = FALSE,
                       position = "below")

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = states_splt2, aes(fill = ns)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())


